# How can I achieve similar URL with asp.net MVC routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and URL routing seems to be a very tough chapter in whole MVC. I read many blog post and many other SO questions but none of them helped the way to understand every aspect of routing.

I would like to have a URL likes www.sitename.com/controller/action/username/userid. How can I do it with MVC routing? A detailed answer to cover every aspect of it would be very helpful.

Comment: This is not technical question, You need read Microsoft documents and maybe additional books about routing on ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

**1.  Using Traditional convention-based routing**

Update your route registrations to include this new url pattern. Make sure you do this before registering the default route registration.

So in your RouteConfig file

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{userName}/{userId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Details" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default2",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This will route **all the requests matching that url pattern to the corresponding controller's action method** (with the 2 parameters). This means, If you have 2 controllers, both having an action method with userName and userId params, based on your controller & action method name in the request url, the corresponding method will be returned.

**2. Attribute Routing**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  [Route("Home/Details/{userName}/{userId}")]
  public ActionResult Details(string userName,int userId)
  {      
    return Content("Details : "+userName + userId);
  }
```

}

Here we are registering the new route which says when the request url is `Home/Details/{userName}/{userId}`, return the response from Details action method of Home controller. ( This is very **specific** as we define specific controller name and action name)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) is an official article on ASP.NET MVC **Attribute** Routing which for most scenarios is sufficient. Sometimes in advanced scenarios you need to configure routes in the Global.asax/Bootstrapper.

Basically it would look like:

```
[RoutePrefix("Controller")]
public class Controller : Controller
{
     [Route("action/{username}/{userid:int}")]
     public ActionResult Action(string username, int userid){}
}
```

I did that from memory so it might not be exactly right, please refer to the documentation in that link and what's on MSDN.